# returning a JSON formatted file via WCF

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

We've seen a number of posts relating to JSON data returns via WCF, but they all cover the aspect of converting object to JSON and then returning that object converted to JSON via the magic of attributes.
We've got a number of preformatted JSON files that we want to return via an WCF service. Essentially all we need to do is read the files in (or a cached copy of of the file) and then return the data as a string . I think ... It seems wasteful to read in the JSON file, serialize it to an object then deserialize back to JSON.. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

When using the WebHttpBinding, this is as simple as creating a WebGet annotated method with a Stream return type:

```
[WebGet]
public Stream GetFile(Int32 someId)
{
  //your logic to lookup or create the file here.

  //Open the file (a MemoryStream would be acceptible as well if you were creating the data on the fly
  Stream stream = File.OpenRead(yourFilePath);

  //register an event to clean up the temporary file (if necessary)
  OperationContext.Current.OperationCompleted += (s, e) =>
  {
    File.Delete(yourFilePath);
  };

  return stream;

}
```